# Why the function sequence does not converge uniformly

Tags: continuity, uniform-convergence

$f_n : \Bbb R → \Bbb R$ : $f_n (x) = \frac{nx}{1+|nx|}$

a) To show that the function sequences f are continuous for all n ∈ ℕ.

b) Determine the limit function

c) Why the function sequence does not converge uniformly

My proposed solution:

a) Since for all n $f_n$ is the quotient of 2 continuous functions and the denominator never becomes 0, fn is continuous for all n, actually this is the easiest part.

b) I calculated the limit and got 1 for x>0 and -1 for x<o.

c) Can we say that because f(x) from part b) is not continuous --> fn is not uniformly convergent ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: c): This is why a) is important.

Comment: I have written the problem at part c)

Comment: Calculate $f_n(1/n)$ and observe that there is no uniform convergence on $(0,1].$ It is typical when $f_n(x)=g(nx)$ for a function $g.$

Comment: If $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly then :
$$\|f_n\|_{\infty} \to 0$$
In your case :
$$\|f_n\|_{\infty} = 1 \to 1 \neq 0$$

Comment: @Essaidi The author was after the convergence of the sequence, not the series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) $f_n$ is continuous for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ because it is the quotient of continuous functions whose the denominator is always positive

The answer you gave in b) it is correct and so it is the answer to c). If $f_n$ converged uniformily then the limit function would need to be continuous. [More info](https://brilliant.org/wiki/uniform-convergence/)